# How to enter HTML line break <br/> in HTML Webform Editor SourceView, Shift + Enter doesn't work

Tags: html, visual-studio, editor, line-breaks

I switched from an older VS version to VS 2015 Community Edition. I'm banging my head against the wall why I can't enter a HTML line break with Shift + Enter in the SourceView of the Editor anymore. Enter creates a paragraph p-tag, but Shift + Enter does not enter a line break br-tag anymore. It just does nothing. I haven't found any information searching on google or various forums. I haven't found an option to add that specific keyboard shortcut. I can't believe that no one else has this problem. It is probably something very simple. It drives me nuts.

Marcus

Comment: I can't believe that there is still no solution. I reported it as a bug, but even 2016 doesn't work right. Is nobody entering line breaks in html in design view anymore? 

I found a little workaround. If I copy <br/> from source view I can paste it in design view and it creates a new line. Does anyone know how to put this on a shortcut? There seems to be no solution from within VS, because apparently it needs to come from the clipboard copied from source view.